# How to cast to a type of typealias T?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Given some protocol:

```
protocol CellConfigurable {
    typealias CellType

    func configureCell(type: CellType)
}
```

And a concrete class:

```
class SomeCellConfigClass: CellConfigurable {
   typealias CellType = SomeUITableViewCellSubclass

   func configureCell(type: CellType) {
      // do something    
   }
}
```

How would you cast an object to T? e.g.

```
let cell = // dequeue a cell
let cellConfigObj = SomeCellConfigClass()
// can't do the following because cell is of type UITableViewCell
// and it expects a type of CellType
// someObj.configureCell(cell)

// So, we need to cast cell to CellType...but how? The following doesn't work
if let cell = cell as? someObj.CellType {
  someObj.configureCell(cell)
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I follow, how it could possible know the type at compile time. What are you trying to do exactly? Maybe there's a simpler way

Comment: It knows the type via generics and associated types. For example, the `configure(type: T)` func in SomeClass correctly disambiguates the type as `SomeType`, but to call that func I need an object cast as type T. Think about dequeuing a UITableViewCell and needing to pass that cell to a configure func.

Comment: What you have there is double dispatch perhaps. You want a separate call for each class type? (I mean like, it's overloaded per type?) setup(item: A), setup(item: B) etc?

Comment: The typealias already provides a way to pass a specific type to the configure method, but I need to cast to that type.

Comment: I'm just thinking outlaid, but what if you have the someObj call configure itself, as it should know how to do that right? Double Dispatch / Visitor Pattern

Comment: Updated the example to provide a more clear case of what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: Why not just use the interface? if let cell = cell as? CellConfigurable

Comment: As a note of style if you are convinced your cell is _ALWAYS_ CellConfigurable then dequeue it and append as! UITableViewCell: CellConfigurable

Comment: Please look at the code again. CellConfigurable is not a UITableViewCell subclass. CellType is.

Comment: I see. Would it not make more sense to just have all your cells implement CellConfigurable and refer to it as such? I'm just wondering..

Comment: WIthout a protocol, there is no way to enforce that each cell implements a configureCell function.

Comment: I see, ok it's like a cell configuration factory. Sorry for the delay. I think your best approach is still to use double dispatch and allow the object being called to determine its own action base on its type.

Comment: IF you specify that each cell IS a CellConfigurable. You are forced to implement it. (non optional methods)

Comment: I see your point. My personal approach would be to apply a generic configure method and let the cell determine if the object is of the right type, this allowing a single universal configure: AnyClass parameter.